# Oracle unique constraint or index

Tags: oracle, constraints

If I had the following table in an Oracle database:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE
(   
"MYUNIQUEIDCOL" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL, 
"VAN" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL, 
"STATUS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL
)
```

I would like a van (of which there could be many) to only ever have one row with a status of "Active" - what kind of constraint would I need to ensure the illustration below does not happen (ie. rows 2 & 5 should not have been allowed)

```
MYUNIQUEIDCOL | VAN  | STATUS
1               100    Active
2               100    Active
3               100    Cancelled
4               200    Active
5               200    Active
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create unique index on mentioned column with the condition as following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_VAN_STATUS
ON TESTTABLE (VAN, CASE WHEN STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN STATUS END);
```

Example:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES (1, 100, 'ACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES (1, 100, 'INACTIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES (1, 100, 'ACTIVE');
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES (1, 100, 'ACTIVE')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEJASH.UQ_VAN_STATUS) violated


SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Can this be extended to use one of two values (ie. if a row exists with Active status, do not allow an insert which is either Active OR Inactive) ?